# Negative negligible functions

Tags: symmetric, provable-security, negligible

If f(n) is a negligible function, is -f(n) also negligible by definition?
Since
$$f(n) < \frac{1}{p(n)}$$ for all positive polynomials $p(n)$ and for some integer N such that $n > N$

Thus
$$-f(n) < \frac{1}{p(n)}$$

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the standard definition, a negative quantity is always negligible. This does not matter, however, because when a definition demands that a quantity be negligible, that quantity is virtually always non-negative (*e.g.*, a probability or an absolute value).